# I want to create a text editor in c, but i'm getting a error

Tags: c

I want to create a text editor using C.
The program compiles without any errors, but when I execute the code and it attempts to create a file, the terminal is giving me an error.
It also gives the same error when I try to use an existing .txt file:

```
./a.out
Enter the filename: hello
Enter the start line number: 1
Enter the end line number: 9
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is the code causing the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1024

void edit_lines(char* buffer, int start_line, int end_line) {
    char* start = buffer;

    // Move the start pointer to the start_line position
    for (int i = 0; i < start_line - 1; i++) {
        start = strchr(start, '\n');
        if (start == NULL) {
            printf("Error: Invalid line number\n");
            return;
        }
        start++;
    }

    char* end = start;

    // Move the end pointer to the end_line position
    for (int i = start_line; i < end_line; i++) {
        end = strchr(end, '\n');
        if (end == NULL) {
            printf("Error: Invalid line number\n");
            return;
        }
        end++;
    }

    char* line_end = strchr(end, '\n');
    if (line_end) {
        *line_end = '\0'; 

        char saved[MAX_LINE_LENGTH] = {0};
        strncpy(saved, line_end + 1, sizeof(saved) - 1); 
        saved[sizeof(saved) - 1] = '\0'; 

        char new_lines[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
        printf("Enter the new lines (press Enter twice to finish):\n");
        fgets(new_lines, sizeof(new_lines), stdin);
        char* nl_pos = strchr(new_lines, '\n');
        while (nl_pos) {
            *nl_pos = '\0';
            strcat(start, new_lines);
            strcat(start, "\n");
            fgets(new_lines, sizeof(new_lines), stdin);
            nl_pos = strchr(new_lines, '\n');
        }
        strcat(start, saved);
    } else {
        printf("Error: Invalid line number\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char* buffer = NULL;
    FILE* f;
    char filename[1024] = {0};

    if (argc < 2) {
        // Create a new file
        printf("Enter the filename: ");
        fgets(filename, sizeof(filename), stdin);
        filename[strcspn(filename, "\n")] = '\0'; 

        f = fopen(filename, "w");
        if (!f) {
            printf("Error creating file %s\n", filename);
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        // Open an existing file
        f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (!f) {
            printf("Error opening file %s\n", argv[1]);
            return 1;
        }

        // Get the size of the file
        if (fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END) != 0) {
            printf("Error seeking end of file %s\n", argv[1]);
            fclose(f);
            return 1;
        }
        long file_size = ftell(f);
        rewind(f);

        // Allocate memory for the buffer
        buffer = (char*)malloc(file_size + 1);
        if (buffer == NULL) {
            printf("Error allocating memory\n");
            fclose(f);
            return 1;
        }

        // Read the file contents into the buffer
        if (fread(buffer, 1, file_size, f) != file_size) {
            printf("Error reading file %s\n", argv[1]);
            free(buffer);
            fclose(f);
            return 1;
        }
        buffer[file_size] = '\0'; 

        fclose(f);
    }

    int start_line = 0, end_line = 0;
    printf("Enter the start line number: ");
    scanf("%d", &start_line);
    printf("Enter the end line number: ");
    scanf("%d", &end_line);

    edit_lines(buffer, start_line, end_line);

    f = fopen(argc < 2 ? filename : argv[1], "w");
    if (!f) {
        printf("Error opening file %s for writing\n", argc < 2 ? filename : argv[1]);
        free(buffer);
        return 1;
    }

    if (fwrite(buffer, strlen(buffer), 1, f) != 1) {
        printf("Error writing to file %s\n", argc < 2 ? filename : argv[1]);
        free(buffer);
        fclose(f);
        return 1;
    }

    free(buffer);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

What is causing this error?
[c](/questions/tagged/c)

Comment: As far as I can tell, you only allocate memory for your `buffer` in the case where `argc >= 2`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you run your program in a debugger it should show you where the error was detected. Then you can inspect the variables used around that place and compare with expected values.

Comment: Use a debugger, see the backtrace where the crash happens.

Comment: The size of a text file isn't always the amount of memory it needs. You should capture the return value from `fread` to know the actual bytes read, and use that to terminate the array.

Comment: `if (fread(buffer, 1, file_size, f) != file_size)` makes sense when `'\n'` is encoded as a `'\n'` but not when encoded as a `"\r\n"`.  I suggest a single pass approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
➜ gcc -g3 debug.c
➜ valgrind ./a.out
==3058== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3058== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL d, by Julian Seward et al.
==3058== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3058== Command: ./a.out
==3058==
Enter the filename: hello
Enter the start line number: 1
Enter the end line number: 9
==3058== Invalid read of size 1
==3058==    at 0x484E9F4: index (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3058==    by 0x10945C: edit_lines (debug.c:24)
==3058==    by 0x1099AB: main (debug.c:116)
==3058==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==3058==
==3058==
==3058== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3058==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==3058==    at 0x484E9F4: index (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3058==    by 0x10945C: edit_lines (debug.c:24)
==3058==    by 0x1099AB: main (debug.c:116)
==3058==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==3058==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==3058==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==3058==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==3058==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==3058==
==3058== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3058==     in use at exit: 2,520 bytes in 3 blocks
==3058==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 0 frees, 2,520 bytes allocated
==3058==
==3058== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3058==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3058==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3058==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3058==    still reachable: 2,520 bytes in 3 blocks
==3058==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3058== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3058==
==3058== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==3058== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
[1]    3058 segmentation fault  valgrind ./a.out
```

That what you need to look for :

```
==3058== Invalid read of size 1
==3058==    at 0x484E9F4: index (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3058==    by 0x10945C: edit_lines (debug.c:24)
==3058==    by 0x1099AB: main (debug.c:116)
==3058==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==3058==
==3058==
==3058== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3058==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==3058==    at 0x484E9F4: index (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3058==    by 0x10945C: edit_lines (debug.c:24)
==3058==    by 0x1099AB: main (debug.c:116)
```

In the flowing loop, `char* end` = `NULL` :

```
char* end = start;

// Move the end pointer to the end_line position
for (int i = start_line; i < end_line; i++) {
    end = strchr(end, '\n');
    if (end == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Invalid line number\n");
        return;
    }
    end++;
}
```

Comment: I think you could substantially improve your answer by adding some more explanation to your code blocks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you create a new file, you don't allocate any space for the buffer.  The variable `buffer` remains null, which is passed to the function `edit_lines`.  The loop to set `start` is skipped because the user chose to start with line 1.  The loop to set `end` then dereferences a null pointer.  The triggers a memory fault, and the program crashes.